# Div within a div (theory)

Tags: html, positioning

This may sound absolute blindingly stupid but I'm new to website design.

Is it possible to have divs within divs?

I want to use the first div to create the footer and give it a background colour, and maintain a size (1920 x 300) and that's all. I then want the next div to allow me to list some links to other pages and position them (that's the second div's only task) and the third div to hold some images and position them (third div's only task)

Or am I making a mountain out of a molehill and missing a much easier way to do this?

Comment: @AlexB That will become a divsoup tho :D

Comment: This is quite common practice actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have infinite sympathy for you, since I was going through the same process about a year ago.
Read all of the excellent suggestions noted above, but the best way to learn it is to do it. You can use jsfiddle.net, or just use a notepad, saving the html file on your computer and hit it with the browser. You'll see all kinds of "funny" behavior. I've had so many examples of changing ONE pixel on a div and you look at the page to see a Picasso cubist painting!!

I've put a little [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4486/1/) together for you to play with. Note that once you get the HTML "done", you will spend most of your time with the CSS portion of the code. Best of luck!

CSS

```
.container {
  width:300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
.insidediv1 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.insidediv2 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  float: right;
}
.insidediv3 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  float: right;
}
.yourimage {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
.footer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='insidediv1'></div>
    <div class='insidediv2'>
        <div class='yourimage'>IMAGE</div>
    </div><!--end insidediv2-->
    <div class='insidediv3'></div>
</div><!--end container-->
<div class='footer'>Footer</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can make a `<div>` in a `<div>` in a `<div>` in a `<div>` in a ...

Just look the source code of any webpage, you'll see a lot of nested `<div>`, `<span>` etc...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is Possible ..
for more information Check this links may be help full  ..
http://gostats.com/resources/css-div-tutorial.html

..

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp

...

http://www.echoecho.com/csslayers.htm

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is most definitely possible. This is what `HTML` and `css` are designed to do..

Before you go trawling through the thousands of badly formed tutorials out there, consider a few of the resources for that type of question:

- [nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/?s=css%20layout) has many diverse tutorials.
- [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/), Chris Coyier is a ninja with all sorts of page layout related info.

If you're really keen to get down and dirty with the actual `div`s, then have a look at a few layout frameworks.. These make it dead easy to visualise your "divs within divs" idea while you code the `HTML`.

- [Twitter Bootstrap](http://www.getbootstrap.com) offers a lot of pre-made elements for building pages, this way provides a great deal of structure and conformity in the layout.
- [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) provides less structural elements with more flexibility, however it does make you code more of the `css` to *make* it look just how you want..

Have a [look at this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/OPEdACe/1/) for a very simple example of element layouts in Bootstrap 3 (and resize your browser window). Just click the "edit" button in the top right to see the code behind it.

Whatever you do though, don't over-use the markup. Keep you markup as simple as possible for the content you need to display, then use layout-based `css` rules to put the pieces where you want. This is where the "layout" side of all the above options will help it make sense.

Hope that helps a bit. :)